# How to easily format >100 lines with R ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Goal:

- I am trying to plot hundreds of lines (different randomized trials) with ggplot
- I want to plot all lines besides one - that is the mean of all trials - in gray, thereby indicating "dispersion" around the mean

I found something similar in a scientific paper

[image]

My graph currently looks like this:

[image]

```
Reproducible data: 

    dat = structure(list(Trial = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6"), 
                     `1` = c(69824.35, 69824.35, 69824.35, 69824.35, 69824.35, 
                             69824.35), `2` = c(67628.96, 67628.96, 67628.96, 67628.96, 
                                                67628.96, 67628.96), `3` = c(67976.71, 67991.52, 67973.59, 
                                                                             67939.18, 67983.88, 67955.75), `4` = c(68263.39, 68290.91, 
                                                                                                                    68258.04, 68205.13, 68278.1, 68231.44), `5` = c(68500.94, 
                                                                                                                                                                    68538.68, 68494.1, 68433.12, 68522.57, 68464.4), `6` = c(68698.74, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             68744.19, 68691, 68628.56, 68726.19, 68661.55), `7` = c(68864.2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     68915.02, 68856.02, 68796.14, 68896.15, 68828.66), `8` = c(69003.2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                69057.35, 68994.91, 68939.84, 69038.34, 68970.55), `9` = c(69120.43, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           69176.19, 69112.27, 69063.11, 69157.55, 69091.22)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# pivot longer
transform_dat = dat |> 
  pivot_longer(-Trial)

# plot lines for each trial in different colour
transform_dat |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(name), y = value, colour = Trial)) +
  geom_line()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use `alpha` when showing replications like that, since overlapping lines will appear to be slightly darker than the rest.

First we need to pivot/reshape, then we'll add the aggregated "Trial" of `"Mean"`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
datlong <- pivot_longer(dat, -Trial) %>%
  mutate(name = as.integer(name))
datlong <- datlong %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarize(Trial = "Mean", value = mean(value), .groups = "drop") %>%
  bind_rows(datlong)

datlong
# # A tibble: 63 × 3
#     name Trial  value
#    <int> <chr>  <dbl>
#  1     1 Mean  69824.
#  2     2 Mean  67629.
#  3     3 Mean  67970.
#  4     4 Mean  68255.
#  5     5 Mean  68492.
#  6     6 Mean  68692.
#  7     7 Mean  68859.
#  8     8 Mean  69001.
#  9     9 Mean  69120.
# 10     1 x1    69824.
# # … with 53 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Simple plotting of grouped lines using `Trial != "Mean"` as a distinction for both color and alpha.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(datlong, aes(name, value,
                    color = (Trial != "Mean"), alpha = (Trial != "Mean"),
                    group = Trial)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("FALSE" = "blue", "TRUE" = "gray50")) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c("FALSE" = 1, "TRUE" = 0.3))
```

[image: ggplot2]

Notes:

- add `guide="none"` to both `scale_*_manual` calls to remove the legend, or you may choose to change the labels via perhaps several methods.
- I intentionally did no further theming or aesthetic tweaks, aiming to just show the basics
- *Interestingly*, the order of the `"Mean"` matters. In R, `FALSE` sorts before `TRUE`, so ggplot will draw lines associated with false before it draws lines for true. If one instead uses `==` for comparison, as in `color=(Trial=="Mean")` (same for alpha), then it will draw the `"Mean"` line *first*, meaning that any instance of the other lines that overlap it will mask it. By using `!=`, the true results (the Mean line) will be plotted last among all the lines in that geom.

  In other situations where this ordering is insufficient, I would likely plot two `geom_lines`:

  ```r
  ... +
    geom_line(data = ~ filter(., Trial != "Mean")) +
    geom_line(data = ~ filter(., Trial == "Mean"))
  ```

  to force the ordering. The use of the rlang-style `~`-expression is convenient, and provides more flexibility for those who choose to have more of a dplyr pipe feeding ggplot and want all recently-added/adjusted values available to ggplot. (The use of `data = filter(datlong, ...)` also works but in some circumstances is less flexible.)

Comment: Thank you very much! That did it perfectly for me. To add: I indeed needed to add two lins as you specified at the end of your answer. With the first approach the mean was barely visible, even after turning alpha down to 0.01